# How to covert a single text in a column to row in sql?

Tags: sql

For example I have "Sumit" in a column. I need to convert it into:

1. S
2. u
3. m
4. i
5. t

this format. using sql query. Please help

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your DBMS, but if you are using [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/), you can use `string_to_array()`

```
select * 
from unnest(string_to_array('Summit', null))
```